# How to find out if Add or Insert was done in CollectionChanged handler

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an `ObservableCollection` and I add items via the `Add` and `Insert` methods.

Depending on which method was called, I want to perform some specific operations within my `CollectionChanged` handler that I hooked up to the collection.

The code looks like this:

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<DataClass>();
items.CollectionChanged += this.ItemsChanged;

...

private void ItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var action = args.Action;
    var insertIndex = args.NewStartingIndex;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, `action`is always `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` for both the `Add` and `Insert` methods.

`insertIndex` is `0` on `Add` calls, but also `0` when I call the `Insert`method with `0` as parameter.

Is there any way to find out which of the methods was called on the collection?

Comment: No, from the `ObservableCollection` point of view there is no difference between `Add` and `Insert` so there is no way to tell the difference in the `CollectionChanged`. You need to implement your own observable collection which could make this distinction...

Comment: I think you will need to do some book keeping for something like this,  some sort of tracker like unit of work to understand the changes being done. But can you explain why would you want to distinguish between them precisely?

Comment: `insertIndex` on Add calls will be 0 only at the start when the collection is empty, after that it will be collection's size - 1 whereas Insert would be whatever index was passed in. However this would not be great to use to differentiate since Items "inserted" via the insert function at position `Count - 1` would be considered as an "Add" operation. Is that something you can live with? That's a question for you to answer.

Comment: @Viv No, this is no option. Besides, `insertIndex` on Add calls is always `0`.

Comment: Yeh if that ain't acceptable that's fine, however `insertIndex` is **Not** always 0. Call Add **twice** and use a `Debug.WriteLine(insertIndex);`. Index for Add will be count-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems counterintuitive to check it at collection level, since adding is just a special case of inserting. However, you can solve this by writing two classes:

- One class that extends ObservableCollection or that wraps an ObservableCollection
- One class that extends NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs (let's call it MyCustomNotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs). Just define one new member to track what you need, such as a custom enum.

Now just make the collection class use MyCustomNotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs instead of NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs. In the event handler, check if the object is of type MyCustomNotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs. If it is, just cast it and read the value of the member you defined.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped to manage this problem without implementing my own ObservableCollection, but this seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but came across the same issue and found what I think is much simpler approach. If it is an Add then args.NewStartingIndex == items.Count.  On an insert this is not the case.

```
if ( args.NewStartingIndex == Items.Count )
{
    //this is an add
}
else
{
    //this is an insert
}
```

Comment: Not tested, but if I do `Insert(0, ...)` on an empty collection, I think your code will not work.